# Get Operation Which Caused Changeset to Fail or Get Content-ID of Batch Response

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk

When working with a batch that contains a changeset is it possible to get the Content-ID of the Batch Response if the changeset has failed?

Let's say I have the following code to create a batch with a changeset using the SDK. createDocument3 is going to raise an error and cause the whole changeset to fail:

```
BatchRequestBuilder batchRequestBuilder = new BatchRequestBuilder("/v1/");
        batchRequestBuilder.addChangeset(createDocument1, createDocument2, createDocument3));

BatchResponse batchResponse = batchRequestBuilder.execute(destination);
```

Here is the sample request & response data that is passed to the endpoint.

```
[Thu Feb 29 22:06:11 2024] [10.0.0.2] [pid=4152] [Request] "POST /v1/$batch HTTP/1.1"
OData-Version:4.0
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_17d7a8c3-d3c7-42d4-b6a6-06ef1d975008
Content-Length:2173
Host:test-sapsvcl.aadds.teamson.com:50000
Connection:Keep-Alive
User-Agent:Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/21.0.2)
Cookie:**************************************************************************
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
X-Forwarded-Proto:https

--batch_17d7a8c3-d3c7-42d4-b6a6-06ef1d975008
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_d3c4fa68-582a-46fd-8691-d24272625cda

--changeset_d3c4fa68-582a-46fd-8691-d24272625cda
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 1

POST Orders HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{"@odata.type":"#SAPB1.Document"..........}

--changeset_d3c4fa68-582a-46fd-8691-d24272625cda
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 2

POST Orders HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{"@odata.type":"#SAPB1.Document"..........}

--changeset_d3c4fa68-582a-46fd-8691-d24272625cda
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 3

POST Orders HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{"@odata.type":"#SAPB1.Document"..........}

--changeset_d3c4fa68-582a-46fd-8691-d24272625cda--

--batch_17d7a8c3-d3c7-42d4-b6a6-06ef1d975008--


[Thu Feb 29 22:06:11 2024] [10.0.0.2] [pid=4152] [Response] "POST /v1/$batch HTTP/1.1"
Status Code:[200 OK]
Date:Thu, 29 Feb 2024 22:06:11 GMT
Server:Apache
OData-Version:4.0
Content-Length:569
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=batchresponse_hKXEHg8m-qSXb-TCW6-dl3M-4r2H6qxgAbaG

--batchresponse_hKXEHg8m-qSXb-TCW6-dl3M-4r2H6qxgAbaG
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 3

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 258
OData-Version: 4.0

{
   "error" : {
      "code" : "-5002",
      "details" : [
         {
            "code" : "",
            "message" : ""
         }
      ],
      "message" : "Error."
   }
}

--batchresponse_hKXEHg8m-qSXb-TCW6-dl3M-4r2H6qxgAbaG--
```

After the request is executed, I check the results of each operation.

```
batchResponse.getModificationResult(createDocument1);
batchResponse.getModificationResult(createDocument2);
batchResponse.getModificationResult(createDocument3);
```

The first call to the above raises an exception, however in reality it was createDocument3 that was the cause of the error.

Is there any way for me to know which operation caused the changeset to fail within the SDK? You can see in the batchresponse that `Content-ID: 3` is returned so is it possible to get it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SAP Cloud SDK 5.6.0](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes#560---march-19-2024) has the following improvement:

- Failed OData v4 Batch requests now return the specific failed request from the exception: `ODataResponseException.getRequest()`.

Answer (score 0):

The SAP Cloud SDK is handling this in accordance with the OData specification, e.g. here for OData v2: https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/batch-processing/ (Section 3: Processing a Batch Request)

> All operations in a ChangeSet represent a single change unit so the server must successfully process and apply all the requests in the ChangeSet or else apply none of the requests in the ChangeSet.

This means that the failing third part of your changeset makes the whole changeset fail, so that none of the contained changes are applied on the target system.

To workaround this you could consider adding the three requests into separate changesets, e.g. like this:

```java
BatchRequestBuilder batchRequestBuilder = new BatchRequestBuilder("/v1/");
batchRequestBuilder.addChangeset(createDocument1);
batchRequestBuilder.addChangeset(createDocument2);
batchRequestBuilder.addChangeset(createDocument3);

BatchResponse batchResponse = batchRequestBuilder.execute(destination);
```

This way you should be able to access the responses of the three parts, independent of whether any of them failed or not.
However, reversly this means that if `createDocument3` fail, that `createDocument1` and `createDocument2` are still created. Whether that is intended or not depends on your use case.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the changeset failing means none of the transactions are being applied. However, I would like to identify which of the transactions contained in the changeset is causing the failure.

Comment: Okay, now I understood the question better. To my knowledge there is no such feature in the SDK at this moment. You could to some extent workaround this issue by parsing the body yourself and reading the relevant information from there, e.g. via `EntityUtils.toString(batchResponse.getHttpResponse().getEntity()`.